# How do I get a simple range scan on a multikey index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using Microsoft SQL Server here. 
Given this set up (a clustered index on two columns):

```
use tempdb;
CREATE TABLE mytemp
(
    N1 INT NOT NULL,
    N2 INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (N1, N2)
);

INSERT mytemp (N1, N2)
SELECT N1.number, N2.number
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS N1(number)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) AS N2(number)
```

How can I get the values after n1=5, n2=6 (when ordered by n1, n2)? I have the following try.

```
declare @n1boundary int = 5;
declare @n2boundary int = 6;

SELECT N1, N2
FROM mytemp
WHERE N1 = @n1boundary AND N2 > @n2boundary
OR N1 > @n1boundary
ORDER BY N1, N2
```

It gives me the results I want, but the syntax seems clumsy and it performs two scans. It seems to me that in theory, it should be possible to do this with a single scan.

[Edit] The scans I'm looking at are the ones reported with SET STATISTICS IO set to ON:

```
Table 'mytemp'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
```

Comment: you sure you're not missing a couple of parens there for the OR part?

Comment: The missing parentheses were an accident. As it turns out, order of precedence is expected (whew).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on PCurd's answer, here's another quirky work-around. It persists a concatenation of the clustered index, indexes it, and then does a simple range scan on it:

```
ALTER TABLE mytemp
ADD stringify as 
    right('00' + cast(n1 as varchar), 2) +
    right('00' + cast(n2 as varchar), 2) PERSISTED;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_mytemp 
ON mytemp(stringify)
INCLUDE (n1, n2)

declare @n1boundary int = 5;
declare @n2boundary int = 6;

SELECT n1, n2
FROM mytemp
WHERE stringify > 
    right('00' + cast(@n1boundary as varchar), 2) +
    right('00' + cast(@n2boundary as varchar), 2) 
ORDER BY stringify;
```

It's sloppy, and not really what I was looking for either.

Answer (score 0):

I got a single seek operation when I tried it on my system.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) -
>   10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008
>   Microsoft Corporation  Standard
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2
>    (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
>   (VM)

[image]

Comment: i get the same thing for the query without parens: WHERE N1 = @n1boundary AND N2 > @n2boundaryOR N1 > @n1boundary

Comment: Should have been more clear. It looks like a single seek in the query plan. But the number of scans and reads in SET STATISTICS IO output is doubled (and what I'm looking at).

Comment: I got 1 scan only also: Table 'mytemp'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2

Answer (score 0):

When I run this I get a fairly good execution plan doing just a clustered index seek.

Another option is as below, using a composite key, but this does a clustered index SCAN so performance is probably not as good on a large table

```
    declare @n1boundary int = 5;
    declare @n2boundary int = 6;

    select N1, N2
    from mytemp 
    where cast(N1 as varchar(2))+cast((N2-1) as varchar(2)) >
 cast(cast(@n1boundary as varchar(2))+cast((@n2boundary-1) as varchar(2)) as int)
```

Comment: Scan count is as below:
Table 'mytemp'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: Yep, it's a simple full scan. I'm looking for a Range scan. But the concatenation idea is intriguing